# itemsep is not applied to displaymath

Tags: enumitem

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist{itemsep=\fill, after=\vfill}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item a
  \item \[a\]
  \item b
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

`parsep` works properly. what's the difference between `itemsep` and `parsep`?

Can I use `before` and `after` for setting vertical space of equation?

[image]

This is the result of above code.

[image]

This is the result that I want

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE! Please explain what result of your code you expect. Omitting `\setlist{itemsep=\fill, after=\vfill}` gives expected and nice result where display equation follows the second item.

Comment: What is your use case for the contents of an item consisting of just unnumbered display math material? For sure, if I replace `\[a\]` with, say, `aa \[a\] aaa`, everything looks ok -- speaking from a `\fill`/`\vfill` perspective, that is.

Comment: Thank you comments. I made latex files already and want to change vertical spaces for that files. There are too many `\[a\]` codes (Math Problems)

Comment: It is still unclear, what you like to obtain. Why you like to add some more spacing above/below equations? To my opinion your approach is wrong. Instead of `\fill` and `\vfill` you should use some fixed lengths. Anyway, this space you should change on equation side by settings `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip`.

Comment: I can't set fixed lengths for each code Because I used this code in many places.

Comment: I solved the problem with `\renewcommand{\]}{\end{equation*}\mbox{}}`. Is there better solution?

Comment: We know what is your result, but we don't know what you like to achieve. It is unclear why you like to change vertical space around display equation in `enumerate` list. Make and hand drawing sketch. Fact, that you have many occurrence of your code is not an excuse.  You can do this by use of your editor.  You can also globally define  changes of `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip in `enumerate` by use of `etoolbox` package.  But for further help you should provide more context, what you doing.

Comment: I doubt that `\renewcommand{\]}{\end{equation*}\mbox{}}` is an solution. Newer change LaTeX defined macros. This is very, very dangerous. But it is up to you what you doing. I would consider received comments ...

Comment: @Zarko I added image that I want. Could you give me a sample code?

Comment: @Zarko I totally agree with your opinion. It's very, very dangerous. That's why I need better solution.

Comment: @KuMing, finally we agree about something, but so far unfortunately you stubbornly refuse to answer our questions in the comments. By this you not help us to help you. On such a way you will not get a useful answer (unless someone has a crystal ball in which he sees what you like to obtain) ...

Comment: @Zarko I'm sorry. I want to apply `\vfill` for each item in "enumerate" without change the code between `\begin{enumerate}` to `\end{enumerate}`. But `\vfill` is not applied to item with `\[  \]` code.

Comment: Of course it not. As you set `enumerate` it will not do what you expect because it has affect after it. Your approach is wrong (as far as I can guess). See received answer, it seems to give is what you looking for.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest that you switch from

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{itemsep=\fill, after=\vfill}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item a
  \item \[ a \]
  \item b
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{itemsep=\fill, after=\vfill}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item a
  \item $\displaystyle a$
  \item b
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

i.e., replace all instances of `\[ ... \]` with `enumerate` environments with `$\displaystyle ... $`?

That way, you will also be able to avoid having the item's enumeration number occur on a different line than the associated equation.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

[image]

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\Item[1][]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax  \item \else \item[#1] \fi
  \abovedisplayskip=0pt\abovedisplayshortskip=0pt~\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
  
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}    
\item a\\[2cm]
\Item  
    \begin{align*}  
    \sum^{a}_{n=3} = \dfrac{x^2+2}{x-4}
    \end{align*} \\[2cm]
\Item 
    \begin{align*}  
     x^2+2 \alpha - 4n 
    \end{align*} \\[2cm]
\item d
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry I want to the same result without changing code between `\begin{enumerate}` and `\end{enumerate}`. There are too many codes to change.

Comment: @KuMing This is just an option, and only I showed you my thoughts as a working example. I think this is one of the simplest and most up-to-date working examples...